# JSON Data to dynamic (Anonymous type) conversion

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm having trouble converting JSON data to a dynamic type definition.  I've looked at JObject, JsonConvert serialize/deserialize and nothing works.  The closest thing to making this work is JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType but this requires a definition that matches the JSON.  In my case, the JSON is quite complicated so I really need to convert an instance of the JSON to a fully anonymous, dynamic type.

```
dynamic rawjson = @"{ 'tags': { 'abcd' : '12345' },'properties': { 'desired': {  'PropOne' : '2345', 'PropTwo' : '6789' } } }";

#region reference object
dynamic reference = new
{
    SomeName = $"xxxx",
    initialTwin = new
    {
        tags = new { abcd = 12345 },
        properties = new
        {
            desired = new
            {
                PropOne = "2345",
                PropTwo = "6789"
            }
        }
    }
};

#endregion

dynamic anonobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(rawjson, reference.initialTwin);

dynamic testobject = new
{
    SomeName = $"xxxx",
    initialTwin = $"{anonobject}"
};
```

I need the "testobject" in the code above to look exactly like the "reference" object. Using the DesializeAnonymousType gets me very close but the definition would be very hard to create and maintain.

How can I get the same results working from an instance of JSON data without typing the definition for DeserializeAnonyousType?  Is that possible?

Comment: Anonymous types are *not* dynamic. They're defined at compile-time by your source code. Have you tried just `dynamic testObject = JObject.Parse(rawJson)`? What do you need to do with the object afterwards?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to create a concrete class(es)?

Comment: Microsoft has defined a response object that is dynamic, so, i'm passing the object back to the caller.  Only the dynamic object (reference) i show above serializes correctly.  When I use JObject.Parse(string), the value returned is:   "{\r\n  \"tags\": {\r\n    \"abcd\": \"12345\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"properties\": {\r\n    \"desired\": {\r\n      \"PropOne\": \"2345\",\r\n      \"PropTwo\": \"6789\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"   <string> The reference object is { tags = {{ abcd = 12345 }}, properties = {{ desired = { PropOne = 2345, PropTwo = 6789 } }} } <Anonymous Type>

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the way below and it worked for me:

```
var anonobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(rawjson);

dynamic testobject = new
{
    SomeName = $"xxxx",
    initialTwin = anonobject
};
```

But since this is a dynamic object, you need to know the properties you may want to use.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(testobject.initialTwin.tags.abcd);
```

Comment: Yes, this requires a POCO of the data but i was hoping there was another way.